# How do I remove the gap between the header and image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

here is a simple page with i m trying to develop.

I'm completely new to html , css and jQuery.

there is one header menu and beneath it is a image slider which I have coded using some youtube tutorials. Images fade in and out every 3 seconds.

There is a gap between my header ad the slider , I don't know how to get rid of it ? and when I tried applying a background image in `body:after{ background-image:url(...)}` because I wanted the image to have opacity, the background image doesn't appear.

Any help would be grateful and also i would like to know how do I

1. Add content on my image slider like a description over the image or a link on it ?
2. Integrate video in my slider , mostly a video to be played from youtube?

here is the JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vj1023/57aqkdg2/6/

**HTML**

```
 <header class="mainHeader">


   <nav>
     <ul>
       <li><a href=" #">LIFE</a></li>
       <li><a href=" #">REVIEWS</a></li>
       <li><a href=" #">LISTS</a></li>
       <li><a href=" #">PHOTO-ESSAYS</a></li>
       <li><a href=" #">PARENT'S SPEAK</a></li>
       <li><a href=" #">AGONY AUNT</a></li> 
    </ul>


   </nav>

   <div class="sliderWrapper">
    <div id="slider">
      <Img id="1" src="http://v-pluse24.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/1822-Soccer-Ball-www.WallpaperMotion.com_.jpg"> 
      <Img id="2" src="images/img2.jpg">
      <Img id="3" src="images/img3.jpg">
      <Img id="4" src="images/img4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>  

 </header>



<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>  
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
a
{
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #000;
    color:white!important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mainHeader nav
{
    background: rgba(19, 17,17, 0.7);
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}


.mainHeader nav
{
    background: rgba(19, 17,17, 0.7);
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}




img
{
    margin: 0px;
}


.mainHeader nav ul
{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 ; 
}

.mainHeader nav ul li
{

    display: inline;
}

.mainHeader nav a
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;
}


.body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}



 body:after 
   {
        content: "";
        background-color: white;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-size:cover;
        opacity: 0.6;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
       text-align: left;
    }



.sliderWrapper
{ 
  vertical-align: top; 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#slider
{
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

#slider > Img
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   float: left;
}


.sliderWrapper > a
{
   background-color:white;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-radius: 5px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 400px;
}
```

**JavaScript/Jquery**

```
sliderInt=1;
sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider>img#1').fadeIn(100);
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
    count= $("#slider>img").size();

    loop = setInterval(function(){

        if(sliderNext>count){
            sliderNext=1;
            sliderInt=1;
        }

        $("#slider>img").fadeOut(100);
        $("#slider>img#"+sliderNext).fadeIn(100);

        sliderInt=sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext+1;

    }, 2500);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and change

```
.mainHeader nav a
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;

}
```

To

```
.mainHeader nav a
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #FFF;

}
```

The difference is that there was top padding of 10px in this css class and now there isn't.

**EDIT**: This actually breaks the alignment of the links, but is definitely the problem.

Those errors are incredibly resilient when you try really hard to find them.
What I usually do is hit F12 and start disabling css attributes of different tags, which might be related to the problem.

Comment: Thank you soo much Sir ,it worked. but now do i then fix the alignment of the links ? all i knew was padding was the solution to vertically align them in the center of the nav.

Comment: fixed it , made the margin of the nav -10; and kept the padding of   'nav a ' same as earlier;